# jQuery prevent firing twice click logic inside the function

Tags: jquery

I'm trying to wrap the logic inside the function so that I can apply the same function across the whole project.

This works below:

```
$(selector).on('click', function(){
   var hasBeenCliked = $(this).attr("has-been-clicked");
   if (hasBeenCliked === "yes") {
       return;
   }
   $(this).attr("has-been-clicked", "yes");

  //do some stuff once
});
```

Now, when I create a function something like this:

```
function preventTwiceClick(item){
        var hasBeenCliked = $(this).attr("has-been-clicked");
       if (hasBeenCliked === "yes") {
           return;
       }
       $(this).attr("has-been-clicked", "yes");
    }
```

and then reuse it in multiple times on any click function like this, it doesn't work and it is still firing twice:

```
$(selector1).on('click', function(){
    preventTwiceClick(this);
    //do some stuff
});

$(selector2).on('click', function(){
    preventTwiceClick(this);
    //do some stuff
});

$(selector3).on('click', function(){
    preventTwiceClick(this);
    //do some stuff
});
```

Many thanks for your help

**EDIT**
I did what you suggested guys, but it is not working.
Here's the example: [FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/9hupog6y/1/)

Comment: Use [`.one()`](http://api.jquery.com/one/) instead of `.on()`?

Comment: try changing your paramter of "preventTwiceClick" to "$(this)" and replace $(this) inside your function to "item" (the parameter)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You doing wrong here ,

Try using like this

```
function preventTwiceClick(this){

       if ($(this).attr("has-been-clicked") === "yes") {
           return;
       }
       $(this).attr("has-been-clicked", "yes");
    }
```

Because var **hasBeenCliked** is being  overwritten

EDIT : Else you can use .**one** as @george suggested

**EDIT 2 :**

```
$('#working-test').on('click', function(){
   var hasBeenCliked = $(this).attr("has-been-clicked");
   if (hasBeenCliked === "yes") {
       return;
   }
   $(this).attr("has-been-clicked", "yes");

  alert('once');
});


function preventTwiceClick(ele){
    console.log($(ele).attr("has-been-clicked"));
       if ($(ele).attr("has-been-clicked") == "yes") {
           return true;
       }else{
           $(ele).attr("has-been-clicked", "yes");
           return false;
       }

    }

$('#not-working-test').on('click', function(){
    if(!preventTwiceClick(this)){
       alert('first time'); 
        //do your stuff here
    }
});
```

Comment: Check my Fiddle in Edit

Answer (score 0):

At first you can use [One()](http://api.jquery.com/one/)

At second in preventTwiceClick you pass item,but noy use it,fix it to

```
function preventTwiceClick(item){
    var hasBeenCliked = $(item).attr("has-been-clicked");
   if (hasBeenCliked === "yes") {
       return;
   }
   $(item).attr("has-been-clicked", "yes");
}
```

Comment: If you are to attach custom data to an element, use `.data()`.

Comment: How you can see this is not my code,using .data() - better solution,but with attr() code also will work

Comment: note that you can't mix .data() and .attr(). e.g. you can't use .attr('click', 'yes') and .data('click') for getting the value of this attribute.
Just want that leave here ;-)

Comment: Check my Fiddle in Edit

Answer (score 0):

> apply the same function across the whole project

Does this mean that you want it to apply across your whole website? if so, you'd probably be best using cookies. you can do this in javascript with something like this.

`document.cookie = "elementHasBeenClicked = true"`

then inside your event youd have to check your cookie with

`getCookie("elementHasBeenClicked")`

if you were using a custom cookie checker.

`function getCookie(cname) {
    var name = cname + "=";
    var ca = document.cookie.split(';');
    for(var i=0; i<ca.length; i++) {
        var c = ca[i];
        while (c.charAt(0)==' ') c = c.substring(1);
        if (c.indexOf(name) != -1) return c.substring(name.length,c.length);
    }
    return "";
}`

If you want it to be on a per page basis, then a simple data attribute on your item should be fine - see data attributes here http://ejohn.org/blog/html-5-data-attributes/